# C++, expression can not be a function

Tags: c++, eigen

`Expression can not be a function`, but my expression is not a function, it is a variable.

Show my code.

```
class Data {

public:
    Data(int rows, int partid, vector<MatrixXd*> * res, MatrixXd * a)
    {
        _rows = rows;
        _partid = partid;
        _res = res;
        _a = a;
    }

    int _rows;
    int _partid;
    vector<MatrixXd*> * _res;
    MatrixXd * _a;
};

[snippet]    

void * partitionFunc(void * arg)
{
    Data * data = (Data *)arg;
    MatrixXd * m;
    int dim = data->_rows / data->_res->size();
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j ++)
        {
            m = (*(data->_res))[data->_partid];
            (*m)(i, j) = data->_a(dim*data->_partid+i, dim*data->_partid+j);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

When compiling the code it returned

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
solutions.h: In function ‘void* partitionFunc(void*)’:
solutions.h:86:75: error: expression cannot be used as a function
             (*m)(i, j) = data->_a(dim*data->_partid+i, dim*data->_partid+j);
                                                                           ^ 
solutions.h: In function ‘void* partitionFunc(void*)’:
solutions.h:86:75: error: expression cannot be used as a function
             (*m)(i, j) = data->_a(dim*data->_partid+i, dim*data->_partid+j);
```

But the `m` is a matrix, and `(*m)(i, j)` is to get the value in row i+1, column j+1.

How should I avoid such error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It meant `data->_a` is not function (note the position of `^`). You should do the same thing to `data->_a` as `m`, i.e. using `operator*` since it's a pointer to `MatrixXd`.

```
(*m)(i, j) = (*data->_a)(dim*data->_partid+i, dim*data->_partid+j);
```

Comment: oh, what a easy question, I just forget to add `*`  to `data->_a`. I have spend a lot time struggling `(*m)(i, j)` and did not even took `data->_a` into consideration. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't even see the way you add an accessor tothe matrix. Plus, using parentheses is a function call unless you overloaded the () operator.

There is no way in there to access the data. You are attempting to use m as a function or a class with the () operator overloaded.